# Laravel Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isAdmin does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

На сайте используется проверка на админа/суперадмина.
Код метода авторизации

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $login = request('login');
    $password = request('password');

    if ( Auth::attempt(array('login' => $login, 'password' => $password)) ) {
        if ( Auth::user()->delete == 1 ) {
            Auth::logout();
            return response(array('success' => "false", 'error'=>"Доступ запрещен, учетная запись удалена!"), 200);
        }
        if ( Auth::user()->ban == 1 ) {
            Auth::logout();
            return response(array('success' => "false", 'error'=>"Доступ запрещен, пользователь забанен!"), 200);
        }
        return response(array('success' => "true", 'group' => Auth::user()->group), 200);
    } else {
        return response(array('success' => "false", 'error'=>"Ошибка! Введите корректные логин или пароль!"), 200);
    }
}
```

Код метода из другого контроллера, который показывает табличку юзеров при логине, как админ

```
 public function getUsers(){
    if ( ( Auth::user()->isAdmin() || Auth::user()->isSuperadmin() ) == false ) {
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }

    $users = User::where('group',3);

    if ( request()->has('search') && request('search') != '' ) {
        $search = request('search');

        $users = $users->where(function($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('full_name','LIKE','%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('login','LIKE','%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('phone','LIKE','%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('email','LIKE','%' . $search . '%');
        });
    }

    $users = $users->with('resp')->paginate(50);

    return view('users.users', array('title' => 'Пользователи'), compact('users'));
}
```

Я не совсем понимаю, с чем связана ошибка, если надо предоставить еще какие-то куски кода, моментально предоставлю. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А где именно в модели User есть такой метод? У вас он есть, вы его написали?

Comment: Да, вот он.      'public function isAdmin()
    {
        if ( Auth::check() ) {
            if ( $this->group == 1 ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }'

Comment: И где именно и на какой строчке происходит ошибка? У вас в предоставленном коде я не вижу возможности для неё.

Comment: Жалутеся на метод getUsers

Comment: [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\UsersController->getUsers()

Comment: У вас функции isAdmin() и isSuperadmin() созданы?

Comment: Покажите первые строки (до `class User`, интересует namespace) файла, где лежит класс юзера, и раздел `providers` из файла `config/auth.php`

Answer (score 2):

В описании ошибки прописано, что в Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder отсутствует метод  isAdmin()

Надо искать ошибку не в классе User, а в том, что вы где-то используете построитель запроса, вместо объекта класса User. Где-то напутали переменные.

Судя по текущему коду, тут таких возможностей нет. Так как Auth::user() - возвращает или null, или User.

Кстати, данная структура, если пользователь будет не авторизирован, выведет ошибку. Так как будет null->isAdmin():

```
Auth::user()->isAdmin()
```

Нужно прописывать так:

```
optional(Auth::user())->isAdmin()
```